# How to group by multiple columns in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I have an Oracle table with data in a form:

```
USER_ID |   Group1  |   Group2  |   Group3  |
---------------------------------------------
id1     |   YES |   NO  |   NO  |  
id1     |   NO  |   YES |   NO  |
id1     |   NO  |   NO  |   YES |
id2     |   NO  |   NO  |   NO  |
id2     |   YES |   NO  |   NO  |
id2     |   NO  |   NO  |   NO  |
```

I want to see it like this after select:

```
USER_ID |   Group1  |   Group2  |   Group3  |
---------------------------------------------
id1     |   YES |   YES |   YES |  
id2     |   YES |   NO  |   NO  |
```

Group by USER_ID column and show on a single line all accessible groups for single user_id. I do not want to write scripts. I have found some topics which suggest using `MIN()` and `MAX()` then `group by USER_ID`

I have tried:

```
select 
MIN(USER_ID) KEEP(DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY Group1) USER_ID,
MIN(Group1),
MIN(Group2),
MIN(Group3)
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY USER_ID;
```

But it gives me an error: query is not group by form.

Comment: Why is your first select item an analytic function call instead of simply `USER_ID`; and why are you using `MIN` rather than `MAX`, as 'YES' will sort *after* 'NO'?

Comment: You don’t need to use MIN function in USER_ID column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an analytic query as the first term (though that doesn't actually error), you just need the actual `USER_ID` column; and you should be using `MAX()` rather than `MIN()` because 'YES' will sort alphabetically after 'NO':

```
SELECT 
  USER_ID,
  MAX(Group1),
  MAX(Group2),
  MAX(Group3)
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY USER_ID;
```

or with column aliases:

```
SELECT 
  USER_ID,
  MAX(Group1) AS Group1,
  MAX(Group2) AS Group2,
  MAX(Group3) AS Group3
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY USER_ID;
```

| USER_ID | GROUP1 | GROUP2 | GROUP3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | YES | YES | YES |
| id2 | YES | NO | NO |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=85764547a209a5cd1e3d37c45e0c3dd1)

---

> Group by USER_ID column and show on a single line all accessible groups for single user_id

That could be read as wanting a list of groups with any 'YES' value, rather than a column for each group. That could be achieved with conditional aggregation (which only keeps 'YES' in this case), an unpivot, and then string aggregation:

```
SELECT 
  user_id,
  LISTAGG(group_id, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY group_id) AS groups
FROM (
  SELECT
    user_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN group1 = 'YES' THEN group1 END) AS group1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN group2 = 'YES' THEN group2 END) AS group2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN group3 = 'YES' THEN group3 END) AS group3
  FROM table_name
  GROUP BY user_id
)
UNPIVOT (flag FOR group_id IN (group1 AS 'Group1', group2 AS 'Group2', group3 AS 'Group3'))
GROUP BY user_id
```

| USER_ID | GROUPS |
| --- | --- |
| id1 | Group1,Group2,Group3 |
| id2 | Group1 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e90cdf5a8ebfa49f2f1160a87aa3746e) showing the intermediate transformations.

Comment: Thank you it works, but when I try to add some new column to select for example user_name, it gives me an error "not a GROUP BY expression" again

Comment: Well, yes, everything in the select list needs to either be an aggregate or included in the group-by clause - so now you would `group by user_id, user_name`.

Comment: Can I include all columns somehow in group by?

Comment: You have to list them individually.